# How to handle error when id value of table is null when using Modal confirm delete?

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

so i have modal to confirm delete action, but when the tabel data is null / dont have any data, got have an error because i dont have id to call? but if i have more than 1 data my delete modal code is works perfectly.. an error occurs when I delete the last data in the table.

i have already try :

the error message is :

```
Undefined variable $listproduct on --> index.blade.php)

Possible typo $listproduct
Did you mean $listproducts?
```

my loop function is **@foreach($listproducts as $listproduct)**

this is my button :

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#deleteModal"
        productid="{{$listproduct->id}}"> Delete
    </a>
</td>
```

this is my modal :

```
    <!-- Delete Warning Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Delete" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Contact</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form action="{{ route('products.destroy', $listproduct->id ) }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="id">
                        <input id="id" name="productid">
                    </label>
                    <h5 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this contact?</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Yes, Delete Contact</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Delete Modal -->
```

this is my script to get ID ( I use this when i write this code :

```
<form action="{{ url('delete', 'id' ) }}" method="post">

but still not works
```

) :

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
        let id = $(this).attr('productid');
        $('#id').val(id);
    });
```

this is my Product Controller :

```
public function destroy($id): RedirectResponse
{
    $deleteads = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $deleteads->delete();
    return redirect('products');
}
```

and this is my route (iam using Resource):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
***Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);***
Route::delete('/selected-products', [ProductController::class, 'deleteSelectedItem'])->name('products.deleteSelected');
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't use your own `productid` attribute in HTML, thus you should use data attribute you save your information.
Second, your form in the modal doesn't get it's action attribute updated and thus only One product ID remains in the action attribute.

Try putting a `#` in the action first, and then when an item is clicked to be deleted, use JQuery to update your form's action and put the proper URL and the ID of the product.

Your ID should be saved in data attribute like below:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#deleteModal"
        data-productid="{{$listproduct->id}}"> Delete
    </a>
</td>
```

Form in the modal:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="delete_product_form">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="id">
            <input id="id" name="productid">
        </label>
        <h5 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this contact?</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Yes, Delete Contact</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JQuery code for handling the form's action attribute update:

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
    let id = $(this).data('productid');
    $('#delete_product_form').attr('action', '/products/' + id);
});
```

Comment: My pleasure. Please consider marking the answer as the accepted answer.